# ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED: How to fully delete gzip compression plugins?

Tags: plugins, compression

I disabled plugins by: UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = '' WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';

and also renaming the plugins folder to something else.

I am still getting:

This site can’t be reached
The webpage at xyz.com might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

I did have a lot of speed optimization plugins running, but this error came unexpectedly. I didn't make any recent modifications.

This is what I know about the error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039804/error-330-neterr-content-decoding-failed

Somehow it is still reporting gzip compression in the headers.

[image]

.htaccess of `/m/`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /m/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /m/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /m/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /m/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

.htaccess of `/`:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

Options +FollowSymLinks


RewriteEngine On
```

Any idea?

Comment: look at your htaccess/server config files

Comment: @MarkKaplun added my htaccess. What server config files should I check? It's shared hosting btw

Comment: maybe check for a cache dropin eg. advanced-cache.php in your wp-content folder, some cache plugins add these and they can be still be automatically used when the plugin is gone... just a thought.

Comment: also you only need half of that in your .htaccess, clearly duplicate but that is probably not the issue.

Comment: @majick yes, I have the file `advanced-cache.php` in my plugins directory. Should I delete it?

Comment: well, maybe just rename it to something else and see if it makes a difference rather than deleting it, so you can see what it's in it if you need it later.

Comment: also, could check for a .htaccess in the level above the `m` directory,

Comment: @majick added above. does w3c add some sort of info about compression outside of it's own directory, in other files, besides wp-config.php?

Comment: w3c `advanced-cache.php` outputs a warning when w3c plugin files are missing. if this is outputting as plain text before the gzipped output it *could* produce this error. do rename it if you have removed the plugin and test. otherwise the problem could be with gzip and you should check other solutions from that link (eg. disable gzip entirely in your `php.ini`) so you have your site back until you can track it down.

Comment: @majick can gzip be disabled in php.ini however?

Comment: yeah I think so, using `zlib.output_compression=0` http://php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php

Comment: may also be useful: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/i-am-not-able-to-disable-gzip/6486